# The operation did not complete (read) (_ssl.c:590)

Tags: python, ssl, urllib2

I was testing some function of gevent and greenlet in python 2.7. 
Here is my code:

```
from gevent import monkey;monkey.patch_socket()
import gevent, random, urllib2
from time import sleep
from greenlet import greenlet
from Queue import Queue

def f(url):
    print ('GET: %s' % url)
    resp = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    data = resp.read()
    print ('%d bytes received from %s.' % (len(data),url))

gevent.joinall([
    gevent.spawn(f,'https://www.python.org/'),
    gevent.spawn(f,'https://www.yahoo.com/'),
    gevent.spawn(f,'https://github.com/')
])
```

And the error comes as

```
URLError: <urlopen error The operation did not complete (read) (_ssl.c:590)>
Thu Aug 24 14:26:30 2017 <Greenlet at 0x2d763a0: f('https://github.com/')> failed with URLError
```

and the other 2 url. Any thoughts to fix that out ?

Comment: Try `monkey.patch_all()`.

Comment: Thx, it really works, how's that work?

Comment: Well, read the docs: http://www.gevent.org/gevent.monkey.html ;)